# Blockade for docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to configure blockade (http://blockade.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide.html) to do a load test. My docker-compose file is:

```
version: "3"
services:
  hashgraphnodeone:
    build: "./"
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: always
    ports:
      - "52204:52204"
    networks:
      static-network:
        ipv4_address: 172.255.128.1
  hashgraphnodetwo:
    build: "./"
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: always
    ports:
      - "52205:52205"
    networks:
      static-network:
        ipv4_address: 172.255.128.2
networks:
  static-network:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.255.0.0/16
```

How to convert this to a valid blockade.yml?I tried the below blockade.yml. But the containers are not started properly.

```
containers:
  c1:
    image: hashgraphexperiments_hashgraphnodeone
    command: java -jar swirlds.jar
    expose: [52204]
    ports:
      52204: 52204

  c2:
    image: hashgraphexperiments_hashgraphnodetwo
    command: java -jar swirlds.jar
    expose: [52205]
    ports:
          52205: 52205
    links:
      c1: master
```

Blockade Output:

```
blockade status
NODE            CONTAINER ID    STATUS  IP              NETWORK    PARTITION  
c1              0bd9c188a5e5    DOWN                    UNKNOWN               
c2              ba1af83cad9b    DOWN                    UNKNOWN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was blockade assign ips to the docker at the same time my application was started. So the application was crashing as it deponds on the IP address at the start. Adding a delay of 2m in the startup script of the application helped to resolve the issue.